# Bind Enum Collection in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have following enumeration.

```
public enum Digits
{One, Two, Three}
```

and a property with two entries.

```
public List<Digits> DigitList{get;set;}
DigitList.Add(Digits.One); DigitList.Add(Digits.Three);
```

When this object is bound to PropertyGrid it is displayed as (Collection) and when it is opened (using small browse button) an exception with (no useful message) is displayed. I am confused how the PropertyGrid interprets list of enumerations.
I searched for a solution, but all i could find was about how to bind a enum value, not list of enums.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a TypeConverter Class that will help the PropertyEditor to parse the Enum into a PropertyEditor.

Sample TypeConverter

```
public class FooDataTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return base.GetStandardValues(context);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return (sourceType.Equals(typeof(Enum)));
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return (destinationType.Equals(typeof(String)));
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return (ValidationDataType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ValidationDataType), value.ToString(), true);
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (!destinationType.Equals(typeof(string)))
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only convert to string", "destinationType");

        if (!value.GetType().BaseType.Equals(typeof(Enum)))
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only convert an instance of enum", "value");

        string name = value.ToString();
        object[] attr =
            value.GetType().GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return (attr.Length > 0) ? ((DescriptionAttribute)attr[0]).Description : name;

    }

}
```

After add this declaration to the enums that you want to parse in a propertyeditor.

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FooDataTypeConverter ))]
    public enum ValidationDataType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// None
        /// </summary>
        [Description("None")]
        None,

       .....
}
```

The last step is to add it to the property of your component that will show in the propertyeditor

```
[Category("Behavior")]
[Description("Gets or sets the type of data that will be compared")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(DataTypeConverter))]
[EditorAttribute(typeof(ValidatorTypeEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public ValidationDataType Type
{
    get { return this.type; }
    set 
    { 
        this.type = value;
        if (this is RangeValidator)
        {
            this.SetRange();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the class names for consistency. The type converter is named `FooDataTypeConverter` but used as `EpisodeDataTypeConverter`

Comment: This is a sample code to give the general Idea, I changed the names of certain classes that had Company prefixes, This is a better starting point than I had when I did that.

Comment: @CheGueVerra It works fine when property 'Type' is of type 'ValidationDataType', an enum. But it is not working when the property type is 'List<ValidationDataType>'. `public List<ValidationDataType> Type{}`

Comment: Update your question with your new code, I don't remember setting a List<ValidationDataType> for any property

Comment: Code does not work. And errors in names have never been corrected

Comment: Changed the typo, I'll go check my sample code tomorrow, and fix answer, I did this three years ago